# Change the background color in pie chart

Tags: r, plotly, pie-chart

I am able to change the background color in plotly bar charts by putting `plot_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)'` in the `layout` like :

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(20, 14, 23),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
)

fig %>% layout(uniformtext=list(minsize=8, mode='hide'),plot_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)')
```

But the same command does not work for plotly Pie chart !

```
  USPersonalExpenditure <- data.frame("Categorie"=rownames(USPersonalExpenditure), USPersonalExpenditure)
  data <- USPersonalExpenditure[,c('Categorie', 'X1960')]

  fig <- plot_ly(data, labels = ~Categorie, values = ~X1960, type = 'pie')
  fig <- fig %>% layout(title = 'United States Personal Expenditures by Categories in 1960',
                        xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
                        yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
                        plot_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)')

  fig
```

It has still the white background!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by adding :

```
  USPersonalExpenditure <- data.frame("Categorie"=rownames(USPersonalExpenditure), USPersonalExpenditure)
  data <- USPersonalExpenditure[,c('Categorie', 'X1960')]

  fig <- plot_ly(data, labels = ~Categorie, values = ~X1960, type = 'pie')
  fig <- fig %>% layout(title = 'United States Personal Expenditures by Categories in 1960',
                        xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
                        yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
                        paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,1)')

  fig
```